# Printing contents of ArrayList and a corresponding number in two seperate columns

Tags: java, arraylist, numbers

I just started a new project and right now all that I'm trying to figure out is how to print the contents of my names ArrayList in a column directly to the right of a column with a corresponding number for each object in the list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class EmployeeRoster {

    String name =" ";

    String id = "%03d";
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
public void Roster()
{



  Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter employee's first and last name. (Must fit within 15 characters)");

  while(!name.equals("d"))
  {

      name =  n.nextLine();
    names.add(name); 
    names.remove("d");
  }



   for(Object o : names)
      {
         //System.out.println(o);

  for( int i = 1; i <= names.size(); i++)

      System.out.println(String.format(id,i) + o );

  }

}
}
```

Right now the module reads:

```
Enter employee's first and last name. (Must fit within 15 characters)
Jeb Snow
Rob Stork
Bran Stork
d
001Jeb Snow
002Jeb Snow
003Jeb Snow
001Rob Stork
002Rob Stork
003Rob Stork
001Bran Stork
002Bran Stork
003Bran Stork
```

I know why my program is printing out like this, but I'm not sure how to get it 
to look like:

```
001 Jeb Snow
002 Rob Stork
003 Bran Stork
```

Comment: 1) Since you declared your variable as ArrayList with String as it's generic type, it's better to initialize it with String generaic type - new ArrayList<String>() (also, there's no need to iterate through Object objects, since you exactly know the class of those Objects - String, that is).
2) In the while loop, do not add name to your collection if it is of "d" value. It isn't of great importance for this case, but adding and removing it from some bigger collections might highly affect the performance.

Answer (score 3):

You need only single `for` loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println(String.format("%03d %s", i + 1, names.get(i)));
  //OR
  //System.out.printf("%03d %s \n", i + 1, l.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= names.size(); i++)       {
        System.out.println(String.format("%03d %s", i, names.get(i - 1)));
    }
```

instead of this

```
for(Object o : names)
      {
         //System.out.println(o);

  for( int i = 1; i <= names.size(); i++)

      System.out.println(String.format(id,i) + o );

  }
```